# How does one calculate the confidence intervals of range odds ratios?

Tags: confidence-interval, odds-ratio

Suppose in a logistic regression a one unit increase in a linear dependent variable corresponds to an odds ratio of 1.61. The 95 % confidence interval ranges from 1.19 to 2.54.

JMP calculates the confidence intervals for "range odds ratios" exponentially so that a 11 unit increase corresponds to an interval from 1.19^11 to 2.54^11. See http://www.jmp.com/support/help/Logistic_Fit_Platform_Options.shtml

Is this correct?

Comment: When you ask is it correct do you mean (a) have I read the documentation correctly, or (b) is what JMP does the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the range of your variable is 11, then that is in principle right.

However, I would not do it that way: the 1.19 and 2.54 are rounded numbers, so they are slightly off. Those rounding errors tend to become surprisingly big if you raise it to a large number like 11.